# NumPy genfromxt TypeError: data type not understood error

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

I would like to read in this file (test.txt)

```
01.06.2015;00:00:00;0.000;0;-9.999;0;8;0.00;18951;(SPECTRUM)ZERO(/SPECTRUM)
01.06.2015;00:01:00;0.000;0;-9.999;0;8;0.00;18954;(SPECTRUM)ZERO(/SPECTRUM)
01.06.2015;00:02:00;0.000;0;-9.999;0;8;0.00;18960;(SPECTRUM)ZERO(/SPECTRUM)
01.06.2015;09:23:00;0.327;61;25.831;39;29;0.18;19006;01.06.2015;09:23:00;0.327;61;25.831;39;29;0.18;19006;(SPECTRUM);;;;;;;;;;;;;;1;1;;;1;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;1;;;;;;;;;;;;(/SPECTRUM)
01.06.2015;09:24:00;0.000;0;-9.999;0;29;0.00;19010;(SPECTRUM)ZERO(/SPECTRUM)
```

...I tried it with the numpy function genfromtxt() (see below in the code excerpt).

```
import numpy as np
col_names = ["date", "time", "rain_intensity", "weather_code_1", "radar_ref", "weather_code_2", "val6", "rain_accum", "val8", "val9"]
types = ["object", "object", "float", "uint8", "float", "uint8", "uint8", "float", "uint8","|S10"]
# Read in the file with np.genfromtxt
mydata = np.genfromtxt("test.txt", delimiter=";", names=col_names, dtype=types)
```

Now when I execute the code I get the following error -->

```
raise ValueError(errmsg)ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #4 (got 79 columns instead of 10)
```

Now I think that the difficulties come from the last column (val9) with the many `;;;;;;;`
It is obvious that the delimeters and the signs in the last column`;` are the same!

How can I read in the file without an error, maybe there is a possibility to skip the last column, or to replace the `;` only in the last column?

Comment: Title error does not match text errorr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`usecols` can be used to ignore excess delimiters, e.g.

```
In [546]: np.genfromtxt([b'1,2,3',b'1,2,3,,,,,,'], dtype=None,
    delimiter=',', usecols=np.arange(3))
Out[546]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

Comment: yes you are right, this works also for the above example, many thxs!

Answer (score 2):

From the [numpy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)

> **invalid_raise** : bool, optional
>   If True, an exception is raised if an inconsistency is detected in the
>   number of columns. If False, a warning is emitted and the offending
>   lines are skipped.

```
mydata = np.genfromtxt("test.txt", delimiter=";", names=col_names, dtype=types, invalid_raise = False)
```

Note that there were errors in your code which I have corrected (delimiter spelled incorrectly, and `types` list referred to as `dtypes` in function call)

**Edit**: From your comment, I see I slightly misunderstood. You meant that you want to skip the last *column* not the last *row*.

Take a look at the following code. I have defined a generator that only returns the first ten elements of each row. This will allow `genfromtxt()` to complete without error and you now get column #3 from all rows.

Note though, that you are still going to lose some data, as if you look carefully you will see that the problem line is actually two lines concatenated together with garbage where the other lines have `ZERO`. So you are still going to lose this second line. You could maybe modify the generator to parse each line and deal with this differently, but I'll leave that as a fun exercise :)

```
import numpy as np

def filegen(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            yield ';'.join(line.split(';')[:10])

col_names = ["date", "time", "rain_intensity", "weather_code_1", "radar_ref", "weather_code_2", "val6", "rain_accum", "val8", "val9"]
dtypes = ["object", "object", "float", "uint8", "float", "uint8", "uint8", "float", "uint8","|S10"]
# Read in the file with np.genfromtxt
mydata = np.genfromtxt(filegen('temp.txt'), delimiter=";", names=col_names, dtype = dtypes)
```

**Output**

```
[('01.06.2015', '00:00:00', 0.0, 0, -9.999, 0, 8, 0.0, 7, '(SPECTRUM)')
 ('01.06.2015', '00:01:00', 0.0, 0, -9.999, 0, 8, 0.0, 10, '(SPECTRUM)')
 ('01.06.2015', '00:02:00', 0.0, 0, -9.999, 0, 8, 0.0, 16, '(SPECTRUM)')
 ('01.06.2015', '09:23:00', 0.327, 61, 25.831, 39, 29, 0.18, 62, '01.06.2015')
 ('01.06.2015', '09:24:00', 0.0, 0, -9.999, 0, 29, 0.0, 66, '(SPECTRUM)')]
```

Comment: ah ok thank you for your help and editing my errors.

Comment: @ SiHa, ah ok thank you for your help and editing my errors. If I place in  the (invalid_raise = False) command and the hole line #4 get deleted. But I need these line ( I need respectively the third column in each line). Because the .txt file is longer, and has always values in the colum #3 which I am interrested in . So when there are ;;;;;;;;-signs in the last column I would need respectively the #3 column! Thxs

Comment: @Markus See updated answer, but note that it will be difficult to preserve *all* data while coping with malformed lines.

Comment: I wonder if the `usecols` parameter would work to ignore the excess delimiters

Comment: @hpaulj Maybe, yes. I haven't time to try now.

Comment: @SiHa, ok, sorry for the misunderstandings! Yes you are right, but the loosing data should be no problem in this example! I am only interrested in the rain_intensity column. Many thxs!